# 'WebService' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, web-services

Using aspnet 3.5, vs2008. 
I have a ServiceReference Path set:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
<Services>
<asp:ServiceReference Path="wsWebServices.asmx" />
</Services>
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

The javascript intellesense recognizes my webservice.

When I run, I get : Microsoft JScript runtime error:'wsServices' is undefined.

I have the script manager in a content (for master page)  section.

Is that the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Qualify the javascript with the namespace of your webservice.  Example:
Namespace.Class.Function 
This link might give you more insight http://www.neilrichards.net/blog/?p=51

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention which version of IIS you are using so I'll speak only for the one I'm having the problem with; 7.5.  I ran into the same issue as yourself.  Using the namespace solution many people suggested didn't work because my web application didn't seem to have a namespace.

I'm running IIS 7.5 and the only thing that fixed this was to make sure my AppPool was running v2.0 of the .NET framework and to ensure that the Managed Pipeline Mode was set to Integrated.

I hope this helps somebody.